# After moving from server to localhost it points to main folder index.html instead of showing the site I had live

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am using MAMP and pointing to the project folder. After I access http://localhost, it does not show the website but shows index.html file. I also added db locally, the configuration file I also adjusted. How can I make it work?

**Edit:**
Here is my httpd.conf file: https://pastebin.com/xvQ0CvzU

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] to see how we slightly differ from other Stack Exchanges sites.  We also like to hear about your Joomla story if you'd care to add some text to your profile.  Regarding your question, I am not sure that you have supplied enough details in your question.  Seldom does a 4-sentence question provide sufficient diagnostic information for our volunteers to lend a hand.  Perhaps edit your question to show us what you have configured, the relevant portion of your directory tree, and how you are accessing the index.html file in the address bar.

Comment: Also, if you are rolling out a new project, why not use the most current version of Joomla?

Comment: The website is using 3.9.15 version of Joomla. I updated the tag.

Comment: I added httpd.conf file in question. I followed Patrick suggestion, but looks like the file already has these settings.

Comment: What address you are trying to access, http://localhost:8888 or http://localhost ? I think default local MAMp address is http://localhost:8888

Answer (score 2):

Joomla uses index.php as the base, so check the following:

- Delete index.html if it exists
- Check the .htaccess file if it exists for a DirectoryIndex directive. If it looks like:

  `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

  reverse the order of the two file names, or just remove the index.html part.

*Additionally from the comments:*

**Modify your httpd.conf.**

Looking at your paste bin try:

- commenting out line 141 which is already defining the mime type - perhaps unnecessarily. I don't have MIME type definitions in my httpd.conf and it works fine, so it may be that the browser does the type interpretation itself without needing to be told by the server what to do with the file.
- on line 258, change the DirectoryIndex directive from

  `DirectoryIndex index.html`

  to

  `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

  to help with managing the default pages.

Comment: I deleted the index.html file and now every time I enter localhost, it downloads a file that contains index.php data. What could be the reason for that?
.htaccess file does not contain DirectoryIndex directive.

Comment: That's to do with mime types for php files not being correct. So instead of it knowing it's code, it's loading it as text and not processing it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819121/mamp-not-processing-php should help you adjust your MAMP settings.

Comment: Patrick, I added these settings, but no luck. Please see the httpd.conf in question details, maybe that gives more info.

Comment: Apologies - playing catch up, so sorry for delay.

I just had a look at my XAMPP httpd.conf. Looking at your paste bin try:

- commenting out line 141 which is already defining the mime type - perhaps unnecessarily. I don't have MIME type definitions in my httpd.conf and it works fine.

- on line 258, change the DirectoryIndex directive from 
`DirectoryIndex index.html`
to
`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`